# Convolve a 3D array with three kernels (x, y, z) in python

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have a 3D image and three kernels k1, k2, k3 in the x, y and z direction.

```
img = np.random.rand(64, 64, 54) #three dimensional image
k1 = np.array([0.114, 0.141, 0.161, 0.168, 0.161, 0.141, 0.114]) #the kernel along the 1st dimension
k2 = k1 #the kernel along the 2nd dimension
k3 = k1 #the kernel along the 3nd dimension
```

I can use `numpy.convolve` iteratively to calculate the convolution like this:

```
for i in np.arange(img.shape[0])
   for j in np.arange(img.shape[1])
      oneline=img[i,j,:]
      img[i,j,:]=np.convolve(oneline, k1, mode='same')

for i in np.arange(img.shape[1])
   for j in np.arange(img.shape[2])
      oneline=img[:,i,j]
      img[:,i,j]=np.convolve(oneline, k2, mode='same') 

for i in np.arange(img.shape[0])
   for j in np.arange(img.shape[2])
      oneline=img[i,:,j]
      img[i,:,j]=np.convolve(oneline, k3, mode='same')
```

Is there an easier way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: you can speed up your code with `numba`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [scipy.ndimage.convolve1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html) which allows you to specify an `axis` argument.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

img = np.random.rand(64, 64, 54) #three dimensional image
k1 = np.array([0.114, 0.141, 0.161, 0.168, 0.161, 0.141, 0.114]) #the kernel along the 1st dimension
k2 = k1 #the kernel along the 2nd dimension
k3 = k1 #the kernel along the 3nd dimension

# Convolve over all three axes in a for loop
out = img.copy()
for i, k in enumerate((k1, k2, k3)):
    out = scipy.ndimage.convolve1d(out, k, axis=i)
```

Comment: It is exactly what I need to do. The reason I choose 1d convolution instead of 3d is because it saves the memory for large size of ```img```.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scipy's [`convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html). However, the kernel is typically the same number of dimensions as the input. Rather than a vector for each dimension. Not sure how exactly that will play out with what you are trying to do, but I just provided a sample kernel for show:

```
# Sample kernel
n = 4
kern = np.ones((n+1, n+1, n+1))
vals = np.arange(n+1)
for i in vals:
    for j in vals:
        for k in vals:
            kern[i , j, k] = n/2 - np.sqrt((i-n/2)**2 + (j-n/2)**2 + (k-n/2)**2)

# 3d convolve
scipy.signal.convolve(img, kern, mode='same')
```